# Open Media Storage

Tags: admin, backend, menu, media

To manage media on Magento I'm using the default Media Storage, but the problem for not-so-expert users is that "it's hard to find".

Is it possible to open the Media Storage adding a button in the admin backend menu without having to open a CMS page > click on add image > click on media storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento by default doesn't have the functionality to directly add Media image. I wish it had one like in WordPress.

To overcome this there are two ways.

1) Either you build your own extension having the functionality to upload images in Media folder.

2) Use a Third Party extension for it.

I am not sure whether there are any free extension built for it. I am thinking of building one. Thanks for the idea. There is one paid extension available. I am not sure how much useful it will be to you but the link of the extension is [Magento Image Upload Extension with SEO Bonus](http://extensions.activo.com/bulk-images-for-large-catalogs.html)

**Please Note: I am in no way associated with the extension provider neither I have used it. It's just a result of a quick google search**

Comment: Did you get a chance to implement this requirement as an extension ? Or do you have any inputs on how to achieve it ?